# Forcing Windows Update settings through Group Policy on a Server 2003 domain

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have an existing Server 2003 domain with Windows 7 clients. I'm trying to force the Windows Update policy to download and install updates on all clients at a scheduled time. All existing client computers are set to the default of downloading updates, but letting the user to decided when to install.

I've followed the directions for applying the policy using the group policy editor at the domain level, but my client computers are not updating to the new settings. Do I need to install WSUS to force this policy, or should I be able to set this within the group policy editor at the domain level and have it take effect on all clients?

Comment: I assume you're configuring Computer Config -> Admin Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Configure Automatic Updates for option 4-Auto download and schedule the install.

Just configuring this setting should do it. You shouldn't need to install WSUS unless you're also changing the update server setting. 

What happens if you run the Group Policy Results wizard against one of the affected machines? That will tell you, at least, which group policy settings are being applied.

Comment: Thanks, this helped and let us find an issue with our domain controllers. We had one that was retired, but it was still listed as a domain controller and causing issues with propagation of group policy.

Comment: @JohnSieber Please add this as an answer and after 48 hours mark it as the accepted answer.  This will help future users who have a similar question as yours.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run the Group Policy Results wizard against one of the affected machines? That will tell you, at least, which group policy settings are being applied. This helped and let us find an issue with our domain controllers. We had one that was retired, but it was still listed as a domain controller and causing issues with propagation of group policy.